# In Kotlin, are default parameter values to abstract functions inherited?

Tags: kotlin, methods, default-value, abstraction

In Kotlin, you can define an abstract function with a default value.

Will this default value will be carried over to the implementing functions, without the need to specify the same default parameter in each of the implementations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not only there's no "need to specify the same default parameter in each of the implementations", it isn't even allowed.

> [Overriding methods always use the same default parameter values as the base method. When overriding a method with default parameter values, the default parameter values must be omitted from the signature:](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#default-arguments)

> ```
> open class A {
> ```

```
    open fun foo(i: Int = 10) { /*...*/ }
}
```

> ```
> class B : A() {
> ```

```
    override fun foo(i: Int) { /*...*/ }  // no default value allowed
}
```

For the comment

> I guess if we wanted a different default value for the implementing classes, we would need to either omit it from the parent or deal with it inside the method.

Another option is to make it a method which you can override:

```
interface IParent {
    fun printSomething(argument: String = defaultArgument())
    
    fun defaultArgument(): String = "default"
}

class Child : IParent {
    override fun printSomething(argument: String) {
        println(argument)
    }

    override fun defaultArgument(): String = "child default"
}

Child().printSomething() // prints "child default"
```

Comment: Thanks for this nugget, I did not even try it. I guess if we wanted a different default value for the implementing classes, we would need to either omit it from the parent or deal with it inside the method.

Comment: Cool, you managed to do it outside the method! Using the Factory Method Pattern, if I'm not mistaken... Thanks again!

Comment: To understand in detail:
https://medium.com/@khadijahameed415/default-argument-parameter-s-in-functions-kotlin-210e2bf036e0

Answer (score 4):

[(It's OK to ask and answer your own questions)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

The code below confirms that the default value is passed to the implementation.

```kotlin
interface IParent {
    fun printSomething(argument: String = "default") // default val specified in interface
}

class Child : IParent {
    override fun printSomething(argument: String){ // no default val specified in impl.
        println(argument)
    }
}

Child().printSomething() // compiles successfully, and prints "default"
```

Comment: Why do i get IllegalStateException with "DEFAULT VALUE must not be null?"
I am using Bundle.EMPTY (android) for default value in base class, and trying to invoke in subclass without this argument..